# Need a batch file to count the number of appearances of a string in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to count the number of times that a string (or strings) exits in a text file (not number of lines). Is it possible? So not in C+, VB or any other language, sorry.

Ex: file test.txt:

```
today i was shopping for the 10th consecutive day,
even I was not feeling well and the day was a Sunday
```

Strings are "i" and "day" This should give me the results:

```
i - 5 times, day - 4 times
```

Comment: Why the constraint of a batch file as opposed to some other language much better suited for this problem?

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. Try to do this yourself and feel free to come back with **specific** questions if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Run this for each string you want to find.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Base code by Tom Lavedas ::
set recurse=
if "%~1%~2"=="%~1" goto :EOF
if "%~3"=="" (set count=0 & %0 %1 %2 %2)
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('findstr /m "%~2" "%1"') do (
        set count=0
        for /f %%a in ('type "%%f" ^| findstr "%~2"') do (
          set search=%~2
          set file=%%f  
          set /a count +=1
          set /a tcount +=1
        )
    echo !search! found !count! times in !file!
    set recurse=%0 %1 "%~2.*%~3" "%~3"
    )
%recurse%
Echo(Total count: !tcount!
exit /b
```